# Register different classes to interfaces in Autofac per session?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

What I'm asking may not be possible/recommended, but I couldn't find anything on it online. Feel free to point me in a different direction.

### What I'm trying to accomplish:

Register different *Classes* to an *Interface* in *Autofac* conditionally - per user session

For example, I'd like to take my current implementation:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterType(typeof(RunHistoryRepository))
       .As(typeof(IRunHistoryRepository));
```

And add something like:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
if(UserIsInThisRole())
  builder.RegisterType(typeof(RunHistoryRepository))
         .As(typeof(IRunHistoryRepository));
else
    builder.RegisterType(typeof(DifferentRunHistoryRepository))
           .As(typeof(IRunHistoryRepository));
```

### What I know:

This code is called from the Global.asax, so this will run only when the site is started. Because of this, I feel like this logic can't/shouldn't go here...

### What I've tried:

I've tried the above implementation and it doesn't work since this code runs on application start - not each user visit. I've also looked into registering these types with parameters (and then I could modify the `RunHistoryRepository` logic to select a data source conditionally):

```
builder.RegisterType<RunHistoryRepository>()
   .As<IRunHistoryRepository>()
   .WithParameter("DataSource", "DataSource1Key");
```

But I would need the parameter to be dynamic on user visit:

```
builder.RegisterType<RunHistoryRepository>()
   .As<IRunHistoryRepository>()
   .WithParameter("DataSource", UserDataSource());
```

And again, since this executes from the Global.asax it will register before a user even hits the page.

Is it possible to register these types dynamically for each user that visits the site or do I need to handle this logic elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your service with a *named service* and register a *factory* using a delegate that will resolved the named service based on your condition :

```
builder.RegisterType(typeof(RunHistoryRepository))
       .Named<IRunHistoryRepository>("standard");
builder.RegisterType(typeof(DifferentRunHistoryRepository))
       .Named<IRunHistoryRepository>("different");

builder.Register(c => {
   if(UserIsInThisRole()) {
       return c.ResolveNamed<IRunHistoryRepository>("different"); 
   } else {
       return c.ResolveNamed<IRunHistoryRepository>("standard"); 
   }
})
.As<IRunHistoryRepository>();
```

By the way, I recommend you not to have `if(UserIsInThisRole())` in the delegate but rely on another service that will do the check for you.

```
if(c.Resolve<IRoleManager>().IsInRole("xxx"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So the code within `builder.Register( c => { ... } )`  will execute when a user hits the site (since it's 'resolving' and not 'registering')? Still trying to understand the details of Autofac/injection. I like the Role service idea too, I'll add that in as well.

Comment: @Phas1c you are right, the delegate will be executed at resolve time and not during registration.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple of options here. You can register functions in the container that will be executed every time you ask for a service to be resolved

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .Register<Func<bool, IRunHistoryRepository>>(
        x =>
        {
            var context = x.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
            return isUserInRole => 
            {
                return isUserInRole
                    ? context.Resolve<RunHistoryRepository>()
                    : context.Resolve<DifferentRunHistoryRepository>();
            }
        }
)};
```

You can also use [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#keyed-services) to resolve implementations via an enum or string.

To throw out a curveball, I've recently been registering components '[on the fly](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope)' within a nested lifetime scope.

```
// a component that uses IOwinContext as a dependency
class CommandHandler
{
    // this IOwinContext will be a different instance for each HttpRequest
    readonly IOwinContext _context;

    public CommandHandler(IOwinContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}

// capture our HttpRequest via the IOwinContext object
var context = ...

// create a nested scope
using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope(builder =>
{
    // register the Owin context for this specific HttpRequest
    builder.RegisterInstance(context).As<IOwinContext>();
}))
{
    // this component will be resolved with the specific IOwinContext
    // that we registered above
    var handler = scope.Resolve<CommandHandler>();
}
```

Comment: I resolved my issue from the answer above, but +1 for the resources provided that I can review.